# How to select divs in table with .selectable

Tags: jquery, select

I have a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_1" line='1' number='1'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_2" line='1' number='2'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_3" line='1' number='3'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_4" line='1' number='4'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_5" line='1' number='5'></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_1" line='2' number='1'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_2" line='2' number='2'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_3" line='2' number='3'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_4" line='2' number='4'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_5" line='2' number='5'></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_1" line='3' number='1'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_2" line='3' number='2'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_3" line='3' number='3'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_4" line='3' number='4'></div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_5" line='3' number='5'></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And what I need is.
With jQuery function, which demo is here ->http://jqueryui.com/selectable/
I need to create prety simmilar function.

I simply have an 3x5 array in js and when I select the divs, it changes numbers in this array.

```
-- pseudocode --
var tab = new Array();
tab[1] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
tab[2] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
tab[3] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);

if( $('div').isSelected() ){
    tab [$(this).attr('line')] [$(this).attr('div')] = 1;
}
```

In the demo after you selected the divs, it changed the background.

Here, I would have the array with 0 and 1 if it was selected or not

When I tried the .selectable() from the demo, all page started to loop, although I have jquery 1.9.1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example of your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML 5's dataset attributes.

*Be sure to check out the fiddle example at the bottom.*

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_1 selectable" data-line='1' data-number='1'>1</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_2 selectable" data-line='1' data-number='2'>2</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_3 selectable" data-line='1' data-number='3'>3</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_4 selectable" data-line='1' data-number='4'>4</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_1 div_5 selectable" data-line='1' data-number='5'>5</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_1 selectable" data-line='2' data-number='1'>1</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_2 selectable" data-line='2' data-number='2'>2</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_3 selectable" data-line='2' data-number='3'>3</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_4 selectable" data-line='2' data-number='4'>4</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_2 div_5 selectable" data-line='2' data-number='5'>5</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_1 selectable" data-line='3' data-number='1'>1</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_2 selectable" data-line='3' data-number='2'>2</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_3 selectable" data-line='3' data-number='3'>3</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_4 selectable" data-line='3' data-number='4'>4</div></td>
        <td><div class="line_3 div_5 selectable" data-line='3' data-number='5'>5</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
//-- pseudocode --
var tab = new Array();
tab[1] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
tab[2] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
tab[3] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);

$(function(){
$('.selectable').click(function(){
    var r = $(this).data('line'); //This is your row (in the array)
    var c = $(this).data('number'); //This is your column (in the array)
    //Do something with this code...
});
});
```

Since nested array has a 0-based index, your column number would actually be `[c-1]`.

**Example:**

I've been playing around with it and here I have a more complete demo for you to look at. This may give you some more ideas on what you can do.

- **[JS Fiddle - Working example with styles](http://jsfiddle.net/zHp58/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/SGu3s/1/) what you were looking for?

Also as @Lopsided said use "data-..." attributes when using custom ones.

```
$(function () {
    var tab = new Array();
    $("#selectOptions").selectable({
        stop: function () {
            tab[1] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            tab[2] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            tab[3] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            $("div.ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                tab[$(this).data('line')][$(this).data('number')] = 1;
            });                
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: HTML 5 data-attributes are meant to be referenced via the dataset method. You can use jQuery's method .data('key','value') or javascript's .dataset object.

Comment: @Lopsided - And what happens if the user does not have a HTML5 compatible browser? Please check the compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

Comment: All current browsers should be compliant with dataset attributes. I haven't done the full legwork but it is a very common method by now and I haven't had any issues yet.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! THANK YOU :D:D:D!!!!!!!!
ok, srlsy: I want to really thank you for your help :)

Comment: @MateuszC Can you share the working example with styles?